# Signal 11 thrown

Tags: c++

hope you are doing exceedingly well.

I am trying to solve a programming problem where the user inputs a set of magnets and the program should determine the smallest integer so that this integer is the smallest integer that cannot be written, with the given set of magnets.

At first I wrote the code in Java, which I am much more familiar with. But since Strings are immutable in Java I thought that rewritting the code in C++ would greatly enhance the execution time of the program. So I thought this might be a great oppertunity to learn some C++.

So I started to copy my original algorithms from Java. But in doing so I am repeatedly getting this: "Exited with signal 11 (SIGSEGV)".

I have narrowed down my problem to this segment:

```
if(!contains(magnets, candidateString[i])){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            magnets[checkIndex(magnets, candidateString[i])] = 'a';
            //The line above is what causes the error.
        }
```

With the checkIndex function as follows:

```
int checkIndex(string magnets, char match){
    int i = 0;
    while(magnets[i] != match){
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

When the else statement is reached in the first segment I try to change the first occuring candidateString[i] element, in the string, to an "a". This really seems very simple but for some reason it's not working.

I just started doing C++ very recently and I have no idea as to what this signal 11 is. I read that it could have to do with leaving uninitiliazed variables, but this is not something that I have done in my code.

Would be very grateful for any help, thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here is my *contains* function I tried to use.

```
bool contains(string magnets, char match){
    for(int i = 0; magnets.size(); i++){
        if(magnets[i] == match){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Basically all I do is iterate through, the magnets untill I find a match. If I find a match I should get inside the else statement in the first code snippet.

Also I should surely be guaranteed not to get out of bounds when calling the *checkIndex()* function, since it is known by now that the match does exist?

Comment: What happens if `match` isn't found, and the loop goes out of bounds?

Comment: What should `checkIndex` return if `match` does not in fact occur in `magnets`? At the moment, the index runs out of bounds and your program exhibits undefined behavior. Anyway, you may be looking for [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: Show [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't see any problems in the code you've shown, assuming `contains` works as one would expect. The problem likely lies somewhere in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: But, will not _match_ always be found, since contains(magnets, candidateString[i]) must be true for the program to go into the else statement to begin with?

And if the loop goes out of bounds will I not get an out of bounds exception instead?

Comment: @Augman "if the loop goes out of bounds will I not get an out of bounds exception" - no. You will not get an exception, you'll get Undefined Behaviour (which will most likely manifest as a crash). In C++ you don't pay for what you don't use, and bounds checking costs resources so you don't get it unless you ask for it (by using the containers `.at()` function).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Alright, I understand, thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** `gdb`

Answer (score 2):

```
bool contains(string magnets, char match){
  for(int i = 0; magnets.size(); i++){ // error is HERE - you need i < magnets.size()
    if(magnets[i] == match){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

If this is indeed your contains method, you're going out of bounds in the for loop.

Comment: Ah, I did not even notice that. I must have meant to write _i < magnets.size()_, atleast I genuinely thought that I had. But you are right, and after I made this fix the problem was solved.

A sincere thanks for your answer, thank you very much. Also I would like to bid you a happy weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Signal 11 is [„Segmentation violation“: invalid memory reference.](http:////https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(Unix)). Probably you have no match and than i is exceeding the length of your array (?) of magnets.

Comment: That could be it, but I do use the _contains_ method beforehand, to check if match is in the array. So when entering the _else_ statement, I would have thought that I was guaranteed to not get out of bounds.